# Issue uploading flat file after migrating from office 2016 to O365

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with a VBA code after migrating from Office 2016 to O365. Please find the code below. We use this VBA logic to upload the file from users desktop and save it in a SAP BPC server and trigger the BPC Data manager package. This code works perfectly fine in Office 2016 but when we migrated to O365, the code is not working as expected.

**1. VBA code is below**

```
Sub LaunchMassiveUpload()

Dim objPackageFromSheet As New ADMPackage
Dim suffix As String
Dim fileSuffix As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim user As String
Dim chainId As String
Dim pkgPath As String
Dim pkgDesc As String
Dim pkgId As String
Dim pkgType As String
Dim teamId As String
Dim usrGroup As String

suffix = Right(Application.Caller, 4)
fileSuffix = Range("FILE_SUFFIX" & suffix).Value
user = Range("USER").Value
fileName = user & fileSuffix & ".csv"


MsgBox "Please name the file " & fileName & " and upload it to the ""Private"" folder (menu on the left)." & vbCrLf & _
"If the file is uploaded anywhere else, data will not be loaded in BPC.", vbInformation, "Info"
EPM.DataManagerOpenFileUploadDialog

If MsgBox("Do you want to Copy the last " & fileName & " loaded file into BPC ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then

    Dim path As String
    Dim nam As String

    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    nam = ThisWorkbook.Name

    path = Replace(path, nam, "")
    path = path & Range("USER").Value & suffix

    Open path For Output As #1
    Write #1, ""
    Close #1
    
    


    objPackageFromSheet.fileName = Range("CHAIN_ID" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.groupId = Range("PATH" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.PackageDesc = Range("PACKAGE_DESC" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.packageId = Range("PACKAGE_ID" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.PackageType = Range("PACKAGE_TYPE" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.teamId = Range("TEAM_ID" & suffix).Value

    objPackageFromSheet.UserGroup = Range("USER_GROUP" & suffix).Value

    epm_dm_api.RunPackage objPackageFromSheet, path


    If MsgBox("File Upload Triggered. Do you want to check Status ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        EPM.DataManagerOpenViewStatusDialog
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

**2. The issue we are facing after migrating to O365 is below**

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to Copy the last " & fileName & " loaded file into BPC ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then

    Dim path As String
    Dim nam As String

    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    nam = ThisWorkbook.Name

    path = Replace(path, nam, "")
    path = path & Range("USER").Value & suffix

    Open path For Output As #1
    Write #1, ""
    Close #1
```

The below message is not popping up once the file is uploaded to the server.

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to Copy the last " & fileName & " loaded file into BPC ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
```

Can you please help how can I change the code to make it work.

In case of any questions, please let me know

Comment: What is the value of `filename` right after you set it to a value? What is `EPM` ?

Comment: It might be an issue with the library used for `EPM.DataManagerOpenFileUploadDialog`. Is the function returning?

Comment: Hi Vincent, this function EPM.DataManagerOpenFileUploadDialog is returning and I am able to upload the file successfully. The next steps are not working